# Merge two arrays based on points fields because users have two IDs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

An incentive program. 
The business changed userids halfway through the program so early points are attributed to one userid (in its own field) and later points are attributed to another userid (in its own field)

So, let's say I generate two arrays from the data, as follows:

```
$result_array1[] = array(
        'users_name'=>$users_first_name . ' ' . $users_surname,
         'rank'=>'rank', 
         'users_type'=>$users_type, 
         'users_dealer_name'=>$dealership, 
         'class'=>$class, 
         'users_sales_guild_id'=>$users_sales_guild_id,  
         'total'=>$total,
        );
```

and

```
$result_array2[] = array(
        'users_name'=>$users_first_name . ' ' . $users_surname,
         'rank'=>'rank', 
         'users_type'=>$users_type, 
         'users_dealer_name'=>$dealership, 
         'class'=>$class, 
         'users_sales_guild_new_id'=>$users_sales_guild_new_id,
         'total2'=>$total2,
        );
```

The unique keys I've setup are `users_sales_guild_id` and `users_sales_guild_new_id`, and `total` and `total2`.

The common key would be `users_name`.

`total` and `total2` are points values that need to be brought together.

How would I merge the arrays so that the final single array might look like:

```
$result_array3[] = array(
        'users_name'=>$users_first_name . ' ' . $users_surname,
         'rank'=>'rank', 
         'users_type'=>$users_type, 
         'users_dealer_name'=>$dealership, 
         'class'=>$class, 
         'users_sales_guild_id'=>$users_sales_guild_id,
         'users_sales_guild_new_id'=>$users_sales_guild_new_id,
         'total3'=>$total3,
        );
```

...where key `total3` is the merged value of keys `total` and `total2`.

Comment: Wonderful Amal. Thank you for your assistance. The question doth make sense, though?

Comment: No, I'm not quite sure what you're asking (still). Maybe someone else can. I've edited the question for you this time. Good luck!

Comment: Merci beaucoup @AmalMurali. You are a gentleman.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the arrays as follows:

```
$arr1 = array();
foreach($result_array1 as $row)
{
   $arr1[$row['users_name']] = $row;
}

$arr2 = array();
$arr3 = array();
foreach($result_array2 as $row)
{
   $arr2[$row['users_name']] = $row; // this one only if you need it somewhere else

   $row['total3'] = $arr1[$row['users_name']['total'] + $row['total2'];
   $arr3[] = array_merge($arr1[$row['users_name']], $row);
}
```

Ps: Be sure that users_name is really unique! A lot of names are the same in big data collections.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan for your wonderful insight. I shall be sure to investigate further, shortly. Must eat.